# VScode live server extension no found on MAC

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

why can't find live server extension ?  ON MAC

and why VScode looks different i have been watching videos on youtube and they have bar at left side one of them for extension ,

[image: VScode screen shows extension]

Comment: are you sure you installed visual studio code? not visual studio?

Comment: you right , its visual stdio not vscode , thanks

Comment: make sure to mark my answer as a right answer, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using visual studio not visual studio code.
You can download visual studio code from this link :
https://code.visualstudio.com/Download

and you can download the extension by doing the following:
Launch VS Code Quick Open (Ctrl+P), paste the following command, and press enter.

```
ext install ritwickdey.LiveServer
```